# Installing Access database engine using WIX

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.7

My requirement is I want to install Access database engine as part of my bootstrap. But for installing AccessDatabaseEngine I can't rely on util:RegistrySearch because that is not consisent.

So how I want is I will try to open one .mdb file in my custom action when that fails I want to run the AccessDatabaseEngine setup. Can someone help me in how should I do this.

If there is any URL which is explaining the same requirement it would be a great help for me.

Thanks & Regards,
N.Murali Krishna.

Comment: You can do directory search as explained in the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141774/check-if-access-database-engine-2010-redistributable-is-installed-via-wix