# Check if Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable is installed via WiX

Tags: ms-access, wix, windows-installer

Anyone know what to look for to make sure the access 2010 32 and 64 bit redists are installed on a client system using Wix?

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Access 2010 32 and 64 bit redists will be installed using MSI.

ProductCode: {90140000-00D1-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}
UpgradeCode: {00140000-00D1-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}

Just execute installation and wait for the first wizard page. Then go to %temp% folder. There you'll find log file 'Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 (X).log'

Comment: Cool.  So I can use it with the ProductSearch element in the Util extension.  http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/productsearch.html .  I'll post a full sample up when I get it done.  Great pointer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Property Id="OFFICEAPPFOLDER">
  <DirectorySearch Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Path="C:\Program Files">
    <DirectorySearch Id="CompanyNameFolder" Path="Common Files">
      <DirectorySearch Id="ProductFolder" Path="microsoft shared">
          <DirectorySearch Id="AppFolder" Path="OFFICE14" Depth="1" />
      </DirectorySearch>
    </DirectorySearch>
  </DirectorySearch>
</Property>

<Property Id="APPFILEEXISTS">
  <DirectorySearch Id="AppFolder" Path="OFFICEAPPFOLDER">
    <FileSearch Id="AppNameDll" Name="MSO.DLL" />
  </DirectorySearch>
</Property>

<Condition Message="This application requires Microsoft Access Database Engine. Please install it and run this installer again." >
  <![CDATA[OFFICEAPPFOLDER AND APPFILEEXISTS]]>
</Condition>
```

Comment: It takes few days for me to develop proper solution. Finally this works for me.